# Bandwidh usage from 1 ip

Tags: linux, linux-networking, bandwidth, bandwidth-measuring

I check realtime bandwidth in my server with nload command    so i get upload / download in mbps

But is there a way to check bandwidth from 1 ip

Example ill check how much bandwidth is going to 111.111.11.11   (total in mbps)

Comment: Use `iptraf`. You can define any filters.

Answer (score 0):

nethogs is also a good alternative.

```
 apt-get install nethogs /
```

CentOS/RHEL

```
yum install nethogs
run with

sudo nethogs
```

CentOS/RHEL

```
su
nethogs
```

Guide from tecmint:
http://www.tecmint.com/nethogs-monitor-per-process-network-bandwidth-usage-in-real-time/

Answer (score -4):

you can user any **firewall** software or any **monitoring software** to keep records of all pc's in your network

even you can manually allow someone IP a limited usage of bandwidth.

Comment: no one give the correct answer, i need  a command example command ... 111.111.11.11 something that will tell me just how much mbps i get from that ip